# Can't get data from sql table by jdbc

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc

I  want  to  simply get data  from sql  server  and  use  it  inside  my  java  program  for  this  reason  i have  used:sql server 2017,  jdk10, mssql-jdbc-6.2.2.jre8.jar. by the  way   i dindn' remember  my sql database  password(i mean  i have   forgotten  sql server  autentification password)  that's  why  i have  used integratedSecurity=true  and  add sqljdbc_auth.dll  in system32(  i guess it  works  fine   for me) but  for  some reason adter staring sql server servicies and  adding  new  rules  in firewall for servure connection i can't get data  from server, i gto error  like this:

> java lang classnotfoundexception javax xml bind datatypeconverter

here is  my code ,   **do  you  have  any idea  how should  i solve  this task?**

```
public void dbConnect(String db_connect_string)
       {
          try {
             Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
             Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(db_connect_string);
             System.out.println("connected");
             Statement statement = conn.createStatement();
             String queryString = "select * from tab1";
             ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery(queryString);
             while (rs.next()) {
                System.out.println(rs.getString(1));
             }
          } catch (Exception e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
          }
       }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DBConnection connServer = new DBConnection();

          connServer.dbConnect("jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:51696;databaseName=test;integratedSecurity=true");

    }
```

Comment: Can you verify that the class `SQLServerDriver` is on your classpath?

Comment: You may find this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47422579/noclassdeffounderror-javax-xml-bind-datatypeconverter-with-sql-server-jdbc as helpful. Since you mentioned that you are using JDK10 and the post brings up similar issue working with JDK9.

Answer (score 0):

```
java.xml.bind module and has been deprecated and removed from classpath in java 9

Since javax.xml.bind is sub package of Module java.xml.bind you are getting ClassNotFoundException

solution:-

java.xml is deprecated but not removed from Java 9 you have to run by adding below statement

--add-modules java.xml.bind

if you are using maven or gradle just add the below dependencies



    Gradle:-
compile 'javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:2.3.0'

Maven:-
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
  <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
  <version>2.3.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: thank  you  for   your reply,  by the  way  do you know  if i can solve  this  problem by smply adding xml bind jar  files (p.s  i  don't  use  maven)

Comment: I expected you are using build automation tools that is why I gave that answer.