# Clojure gorilla repl and JVM 10 exception

Tags: clojure, jvm, leiningen

**Linux Manjaro 17.1.11**

**OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 10.0.1+10, mixed mode)**

**Leiningen 2.8.1 on Java 10.0.1 OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM**

Starting a new project for testing [gorilla-repl](http://gorilla-repl.org/):

```
$ lein new app gorilla-test
```

Added gorilla to project.clj:

```
:plugins [[lein-gorilla "0.4.0"]]
```

Get an exception when running:

```
$ lein gorilla
```

the exception:

> clojure.lang.Compiler$CompilerException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter, compiling:(org/httpkit/server.clj:1:1)
>   .....
>
> .....
>
> .....
>
> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter
>
> ......
>
> ......

**Tried:**

There's a closed issue for http-kit on github [here](https://github.com/http-kit/http-kit/issues/356). It is suggested to add the following to the project.clj

```
:jvm-opts ["--add-modules" "java.xml.bind”]
```

or to add to java startup: `--add-modules java.xml.bind`

The lein option doesn't help and the java startup option i tried using `export` in the shell, but that rendered JVM fatal exception.

If there is another way to configure the JVM (which ofcourse there is) I don't know my way around...
I found many references to the exception by searching, but none that assume no knowledge of the JVM mechanism...

examples :
[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47422579/noclassdeffounderror-javax-xml-bind-datatypeconverter-with-sql-server-jdbc)
[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43574426/how-to-resolve-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-javax-xml-bind-jaxbexception-in-j)

**EDIT (work-a-round):**

Decided to rollback to JVM 8, Java 1.8.

I also found newer version of the gorilla repl in clojars.com. and went for [this one](https://clojars.org/repo/kixi/lein-gorilla/0.4.1/)

*Works!*

Perhaps it would have worked with the new Java runtime, but I decided to press all the buttons at once...

Comment: What "JVM fatal exception"?

Comment: it was an exception that prevented java to start, I can't recall the details now as I tried so many thing. In the end I reverted to java 1.8. I will add it now as an edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option is to add `[javax.xml.bind/jaxb-api "2.3.0"]` as a dependency.
However, similar to the `:jvm-opts` the dependencies don't apply to plugins  (like `lein-gorilla`) since they are run separately.

You can either modify the original plugin and add jaxb-api to its dependencies (which I did in this PR: https://github.com/JonyEpsilon/lein-gorilla/pull/12) or you can "fake it" by adding jaxb-api to the `:plugins` vector in your project.clj:

```
:plugins [[javax.xml.bind/jaxb-api "2.3.0"]
         [lein-gorilla "0.4.0"]])
```

Comment: I can see how this should work. I won't be able to test it now since I'm back a version now.